# get facebook post containing a key word

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How can I get all post on Facebook up to some date that contain a specific keyword, just like for twitter https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search.

Facebook keyword insight API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights/ allows to do analysis of the keyword on posts for last 12 days but it does not return the actual post that contain the keyword. How can I get post or comments?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Facebook search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/).

It should be noted though that this method will only return publicly posted status/post. You can't search private status (for obvious privacy reasons).

Comment: Why not use FACEBOOK PUBLIC FEED API ?

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh public feed api isn't available since V 2.0